# Pass a Parameter to a xpath inside @AndroidFindBy Annotation Java

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I'm would like to pass a parameter to a method with a @AndroidFindBy annotation but haven't found any response about it. The reason is that I want to keep POM as much as posible.

I have this line:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='" + String.valueOf(lastImg) + "']");
```

I would like to transform this to something like this: (This code is not working)

```
public AndroidElement getElementWithParameter(int lastImg){
        
@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.TextView[@text='" + String.valueOf(lastImg) + "']")
                
 AndroidElement someElement;
 return someElement;
    
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this doesn't work using `@AndroidFindBy` as the element is being evaluated on initialisation, not during runtime.
Any `org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory` annotation (like `@AndroidFindBy`) will fail using parameters, because on instantiation the parameter is `null`.

The only way I managed to make it work is constructing the xpath using a helper method, and then calling this on `driver.findElementByXpath()`:

```
// Construct xpath
private String createXpathUsingText(String lastImg) {
    return "//android.widget.TextView[@text='" + String.valueOf(lastImg) + "']";
}

// Retrieve MobileElement using an Xpath statement
public MobileElement getElement(String xpath) {
    try {
        MobileElement element = (MobileElement) driver.findElementByXPath(xpath);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
        return element;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        <your exception handling code here>
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you can retrieve the element using String `lastImg` like this:

```
MobileElement myElement = getElement(createXpathUsingText(lastImg)));
```

So, in short: PageFactory annotated locators need to to be evaluatable when the pages are decorated, thus parameters won't work. ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

**Tip:**
Remember to catch exceptions in case the element is not found, and to follow good practice (it's a good idea to put all your locators in one part of your page object class, typically in the top part, to keep the overview)